# THREE.js — create orthogonal cube

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry

I would like to create something that an animated tube, which is basically an extruded Rectangle. The whole this should be animated along a path in all three dimensions.

Please see the image below:

[image]

The green line means the path, the whole thing should be animated along and can grow much longer… The rectangular tube should have a fixed length (from A to B) and move along that path. The important thing is, that the edges shuold be preserved, as one can see in the image.

In following images I have tried the TubeGeometry, which show two significant errors I do not want to have.

[image]
[image]

1. the faces are rotated around 45°,
2. the edges are not preserved

Is there a »ready-made« geometry which can handle this? If not does anybody know a good trick to play?

Thanks in Ahead!